# Installation of CliPP on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 14.04, c++, boost, clion

I am working on a C++ project and I want to include a JavaScript function (call JavaScript functions from C++) in my CLion project. I found the [CliPP](http://clipp.sourceforge.net/) library that can do that, but the installation provided there is for Windows only.

Can anyone help me by providing the way to install the CliPP on Ubuntu?
It will be a great help. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'm not familiar with CliPP, but according to their page last version was released in 2006 - so I'm skeptical to whether you'll be able to use it nowadays (but I may be wrong). Anyway, you could try building it from source for Ubuntu.

Comment: Yes I was thinking of the same. Can you refer me an alternative for the case mentioned?

Comment: See here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2713289/how-to-execute-javascript-function-in-c

Comment: Got the information of Clipp lib from there. Thank you for the response

Comment: Sure... Hope it works out. Let us know what you ended you with :-)